# Getting Exception in authenticating Mongo DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, sha

I am Getting below Exception while inserting record in Mongo DB.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: IOException authenticating the connection; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: IOException authenticating the connection
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:404)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:879)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:709)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:663)
    at com.yatra.product.seo.service.mongo.MongoJob.singleInsert(MongoJob.java:76)
    at com.yatra.product.seo.service.mongo.MongoJob.myRun(MongoJob.java:96)
    at com.yatra.platform.commons.YatraRunable.run(YatraRunable.java:9)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: IOException authenticating the connection
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:915)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:432)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:443)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:207)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithWriteProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:565)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:195)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$8.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:884)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:402)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Unable to find PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1. [Caused by java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 SecretKeyFactory not available]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient.Hi(DBPort.java:829)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient.computeClientFinalMessage(DBPort.java:747)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient.evaluateChallenge(DBPort.java:681)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:904)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 SecretKeyFactory not available
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:122)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:160)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient.Hi(DBPort.java:826)
    ... 24 more
```

Can Any Body help please ?

Thanks

Comment: Paste your config. We cannot say what the problem is in your code just by looking at the log.

Comment: It should be available in the JDK under the SunJCE provider: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider

Comment: Is this one the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019778/authentication-on-mongodb-3-0-5-with-java-driver-3-0-3-and-gridfs

Answer (score 1):

Despite we can't see your code. There are two possible ways to fix this.

**Workaround:** Add the following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
```

And add this instruction `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())` before authenticating with MongoDB.

**Correct way:**

Since, PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 should be included in your java installation folder. In my opinion, i would check if my enviorment variables are correct. And in the case that you use Windows, i would also check regedit `HKLM/Software/JavaSoft/Java Runtime Environment/` to make sure that paths are also correct.

Answer (score 1):

If your java version below 1.6, then use @Charlie 's solution.
Else, there must be absent the system property of java.ext.dirs 
you can execute java like this:

> java -Djava.ext.dirs=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext  yourApp

enjoy it.