# Authentication on MongoDB 3.0.5 with Java Driver 3.0.3 and GridFS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am trying to connect from Java Driver 3.0.3 with the connection string below to a Mongo 3.0.5:

```
mongodb://admin:pass@myIP:myPort/databasename?authSource=databasename
```

but I am getting the following exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=myIP:myPort, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient}, caused by {java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient}}]
```

I have read that MongoDB 3.0 has recently changed authentication API. I am currently using the previous interface client.getDB(), which is deprecated,

```
        DB db = client.getDB(uri.getDatabase()); (deprecated)
```

instead the new one client.getDatabase():

```
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("databasename");
```

This could be the cause of the exception supposing that getDB() is not longer supported.

BUT, the problem is, I am also using GridFS in my project and, currently, GridFS uses DB instead MongoDatabase, so I would expect the DB interface still being able to authenticate on current release because I cannot configure my mongodb to authenticate on normal connections but not authenticate on GridFS connections.

http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html

So, I have 2 options:

- Is anyone being able to authenticate to MongoDB 3.0.5 with the old API (client.getDB())?
- Is there a way to use GridFS from a MongoDatabase interface?

Thanks

Comment: My second question is addressed here, not possible before MongoDB 3.1 http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/153mmceg9d/gridfs-on-java-driver-3-0-must-use-a-deprecated-db-class so it can be a bug of backwards compatibility on a deprecated method

Comment: Here some notes about the deprecation https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/pull/318 "we don't have current plans to mark DB, DBCollection, DBCursor and others under that code path as deprecated. We will continue to fully support those classes during the 3.x series of the driver"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around the issue by changing the authentication mechanism to the previous one (MONGODB-CR) instead the default new one in releases 3.* (SCRAM-SHA-1).

Here is a description:

1. start MongoDB without authentication (commenting out auth=yes in /etc/mongod.conf)
2. change the authentication mechanism in mongodb

   > use admin
   >
   > var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
   >
   > schema.currentVersion = 3
   >
   > db.system.version.save(schema)
3. create a user in mydatabase database (users must be created after changing the auth mechanism)

   > use mydatabase
   >
   > db.createUser(
   >       {
   >         user: "root",
   >         pwd: "pass",
   >         roles: [ "readWrite" ]
   >       }
   >   )
4. restart MongoDB with authentication
5. invoke from the driver specifying MONGODB-CR in the query string

   > mongodb://root:pass@myIP:myPort/mydatabase?authMechanism=MONGODB-CR

The key things are:

1. changing the authentication mechanism in mongoDB (2) and
2. specify this mechanism in the query string (5)